# Incrementaly Updated PDF only showing annotations in adobe acrobat reader and not preview on mac

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe, preview

I incrementally updated one pdf for 2 to 3 times, now that pdf is not showing expected annotations when opened in Preview app on MAC but it shows those annotations on Adobe acrobat reader.
You can check pdf at http://www.filedropper.com/temp_6
what must be the problem ?

Comment: I have downloaded your pdf and compared on both apps - adobe and preview. working fine here on both apps. please elaborate your question more so as to get the quick solution. Also i am confused about "annotations". page number of those annotation will help

Comment: I have added annotations(highlight,underline etc..) on 1st page only, open it in textwrangler, there u can see the incremental update at the end. I tried opening it in Preview on yosemite but its not showing those annotations.

Comment: ok Thanks. I couldn't see annotations in preview as you mentioned. What I have done is opened original doc in adobe and re-saved it with other name and opened that new doc in preview. This solved your issue. Now I can see annotations on first page in preview. So try it.

Comment: No Nayan the thing is I am trying to modify pdf programmatically, when u save it with adobe then there can be chances that adobe will rewrite it again!

Answer (score 1):

The value of the /Rect entries is the problem:

```
/Rect[ 0 774 0 774]
```

This is in conflict with the QuadPoints value which ends in an annotation region defined by the Rect value (a rect with a height of 0 and a width of 774 points). This behaviour is defined in the PDF specification:

> QuadPoints shall be ignored if any coordinate in the array lies outside the region specified by Rect.

Additionally I would recommend to use the P key/value, too. Some readers may require this as well - though it is optional.

Comment: Thanks Setasign for quick help will check it again! But what I found is there was no EOF char in  endobj and 456 0 obj . Putting EOF resolved the issue.

Comment: You're right, but as long as the offsets are valid this shouldn't be a problem... thought it's very dirty and you should fix it, sure. Did you tried to open the file in e.g. Foxit after fixing this? For me it still doesn't work by just rewriting the whole file without syntax errors. Only if the /Rect value is fixed the annotation becomes visible in Foxit (same for Nuance).

Comment: Thanks Setasign, I made changes in forming /Rect entry as you mentioned here http://www.filedropper.com/tempforstackoverflow is the file, Its showing annotation in preview but not in google chrome. can you try opening it in foxit, what must be the issue now.

Comment: Foxit works. Chrome doesn't but I guess its because it only renders existing annotation appearances - your annotation has no appearance stream.